# XCode 3.1.2, header file not found

Tags: xcode, file, header

I have been trying to build a code that has dependencies with other header files that are not in the project directory. I added the paths to these header files in both HEADER_PATH and USER_PATH. However, I still see error while building. It says that the file is not found. I verified that the file exist in the path added to the header search path in project settings.

How do I make sure that all my header files referenced in the project is included and the paths are being picked by Xcode during compilation?

I tried copying all the files to the project with no luck. This is the first time iam using Xcode, so its kind of frustrating. Iam a linux guy and comfortable with make files. Is there a Make file for xcode which i can modify to include the header file directories.

Comment: What if you simply add the files to the project (without copying them)?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check the order of your source files in your target's build phases to ensure that your dependencies are compiled before your source files that reference them.

1. Select your project in the Project Navigator.
2. Select your target.
3. Click on the Build Phases tab.
4. Click on Compile Sources to expand the section.
5. Drag the dependencies to the top of the list.

Comment: "Drag the dependencies to the top of the list" did the trick for me. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you spelled the header file name correctly ? Is the case correct ? Did you use user quotes "" rather than system quotes <> ?

Assuming you've checked all the obvious things such as the above then one other thing to try is to quit Xcode, delete the "build" folder in your project directory, and try again - sometimes the build folder gets in a pickle internally.